# Unity - UWP Build Target support in Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, assetbundle

I need to run a Unity Script to generate asset bundles in a Linux/Ubuntu server. The Unity will be on that server but the assetbundles are built for UWP (BuildTarget.WSAPlayer) .

According to this thread it is not supported. But has things changed over time? Do you think newer versions of Unity will support it?
https://forum.unity.com/threads/assetbundles-linux-hololens-compatibility-issue.493271/

If it doesn't support UWP assetbundle building in Linux, that means I have no other way to create my assetbundles in a Linux/Ubuntu server and I have to go for a Windows server?

Comment: You might need both .. afaik .NET still only runs on Windows but you could probably keep your Linux server and still [let a Windows server build the packages](https://www.google.com/amp/s/seriouscodeblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/21/and-you-can-write-hololens-apps-in-macos-linux-too-part-1/amp/)

Comment: @derHugo you mean by creating a VM? We have to run the Unity project which creates the assetbundles in a Linux AWS server as using a Windows server will be more expensive. Our client doesn't like to go for a Windows server.

Comment: No not in a VM .. you would need both .. the windows one only for builds ... or in general go for [cloud building](https://unity3d.com/de/unity/features/cloud-build) .. doesn't have to be your servers ;)

Comment: @derHugo I am bit confused. I need to do the assetbundle building in a Linux server. Purpose is to do that building process in a linux server. My question is whether we can do that or not